# Portfolio Issue with Isotope filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, web, jquery-isotope

This has been a nightmare. I bought a `Wordpress` template but the support is offering me no help. The issue is that when you click one of the list items that acts like a filter sometimes doesn't work properly when you go to the `lightbox` gallery (clicking the picture). The main problem I encounter is when the user tries to hover the section before it has charged the `lightbox` shows a mix of pictures and not only the pictures of the section that you are. So far the `Javascript` related code is this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Container
var $container = $('.isotope-container');
$container.isotope({
  filter:'*',
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,
  }
});

// Isotope Button
$('#options li a').click(function(){
    var n = jQuery.queue( $( 'class' )[ 0 ], 'fx' );
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({
    filter:selector,
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false,
    }
  });
  return false;
});

var $optionSets = $('#options'),
  $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('#options');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected'); 

    $('.foliobox').removeClass('active');      
    $container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function() {
      $('.foliobox').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
           if($this.is(':visible')){
              $this.addClass('active')
           }
      })
    } )

  });
```

});

I guess that this is isotope caller.
I can post the rest of the code that calls the `lightbox`. I guess as an idea what could be done is add a fake button in the top of the gallery with a z-index and hide it when the function is complete. Could you help me with that? I am not good at all at `javascript`.

Here is the website: http://donarnold.com.au/

Many thanks!